# Additional casting when receiving elements from a enumeration with specified type

Tags: java, oop

This code I have "inherited" by some precursor:

```
 Enumeration<String> queryParams = request.getParameterNames();

 while (queryParams.hasMoreElements()) {
     // Casting the received element to String.
     String param = (String) queryParams.nextElement();             
     String val = request.getParameter(param);

      // ... do more stuff.
 }
```

I like to remove the casting to String. Because, if I get it right, then it doesn't make any sense.

The Enumeration is created with a type specified, so it can't store (and in turn return) anything else but String.

But before I mess things up (perhaps there is something which I'm not aware of ...?):

**Does the casting to String make any sense?**

Comment: Does compiler making any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using `ServletRequest` class's `getParameterNames()` method to get all the parameter names. [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames()) javadoc for it and this is what it says:

> Returns an Enumeration of String objects containing the names of the
>   parameters contained in this request. If the request has no
>   parameters, the method returns an empty Enumeration.

As it already returns `Enumeration` of `String` and you are defining `<String>` type, you don't need to cast it to string while getting an element, that is redundant (in fact, compiler will perform that casting for you as `Type` information is removed after compile time because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)).

Answer (score 2):

The casting is redundant, that's the whole point of generics- your `Enumeration` can hold *only* strings.
Feel free to drop it, you should.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct.  The type cast is unnecessary and could be safely removed, but it's also perfectly harmless.  Go ahead and remove it if it bothers you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to downcast to string as you have defined enum of type string so it can only hold strings, so you don't need to downcast, also if you are facing any problem you need to add some more code in question

Thanks